# P22 Underground font

Tags: fonts

Can you produce a working TeX-example that use [P22 Underground](https://fonts.adobe.com/fonts/p22-underground) font?

Comment: if you have the font use lualatex and just add `\usepackage{fontspec}\setmainfont{P22 Underground  Book}`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I get ! Package fontspec Error: The font "P22UndergroundBook" cannot be found. It is TeX Live 2019 --- should I upgrade it?

Comment: well have you bought the font? TeX can not use it if you do not have it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have purchased a license to and installed the fonts, you can use them this way:

```
\documentclass[14pt]{beamer}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}
\setsansfont{P22 Underground Pro Book}[
  Numbers=OldStyle,
  StylisticSet={3,7}]% or “Light” or “Demi”, etc., in place of “Book”, depending which weights you have
\newfontface\engr{P22 Underground Engraved}
\linespread{1.035}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{\engr P22 Underground}

  The P22 Underground fonts started in 1997 as the first and only
  officially licensed revival of Edward Johnston’s London Underground
  railway lettering. Drawn by Richard Kegler, this design sought to be
  as true to the original as possible. In 2007, Paul Hunt revised and
  expanded the fonts into a massive character set with several
  additional weights, expansive language support, and slight stylistic
  revisions.% from https://p22.com/family-Underground
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Comment: This file does not work for me, it seems that the fonts are not installed --- could you indicate the needed steps? (I never had to do it before.)

Comment: The steps depend on your operating system. Which do you use?

Comment: Linux, it seems I have to add fonts to ~/.fonts/ --- but where one can get them?

Comment: From https://p22.com/

Comment: One more question: can I make lualatex where to find fonts? say if I want to add them closer to the tex-file?

Comment: If I understand your question, yes, you can put the font files in the same directory as your document and call them by filename; see §2.2 of the `fontspec` manual.